# C meta macro pattern matching

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some macros `KEY_*`. I want to define them all as extern variables, but the number and name may vary.

file1.h:

```
#define KEY_FOO 200
...
#define KEY_ASDFG 423
```

file2.c after preprocessor:

```
#include <file1.h>
// Something like this should be generated by macros or so, but should not hardcode the names (except KEY_)
extern int key_foo; int key_foo = 200;
...
extern int key_asdfg; int key_asdfg = 423;
```

Can (and how) do I make a one meta macro/something that works like this and doesn't need to be called with `FOO`/`ASDFG`?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You question is not clear. Where do FOO and ASDFG come from if not supplied in a macro call?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using only the C preprocessor.

At the least, it would require breaking down the `KEY_FOO` tokens into their constituent characters, and there is no preprocessor facility to do that.

It should be easy to do with sed or perl, or you could even write a C program to perform this transformation, but you can't do it in the preprocessor.

Comment: no, I currently have #define defkey(name, value) extern int key_ ## name; int key_ ## name = KEY_ ## value
I want it to not need me to manually input the name and macro name.

Comment: @fread2281, exactly what don't you want to input by hand? If your `FOO` and `ASDFG` and respective values come, e.g, from a file, your best bet is to use Perl, or write a auxiliary C program that writes the header file with the macro definitions and anything else you'd need.